# Conversion from object to string in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formatting, date

I'm trying to take information from Google Sheets and use it to send an email with the information given in sheets. I have the email part down, but when I try to `editAsText` to delete unwanted characters it won't allow me to. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var start = row[5];
returns: Fri Feb 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (SAST)
```

and I want to edit that to be:

```
Fri Feb 20 2015
```

Comment: Which answer of Vidar did you accept? The first or the one that he added later?

Comment: _Okay i found root of my problem there were some issues with the form that is linked to the spreadsheet, I got it working now thanks._. What was the root of the problem Daniel? We might learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically wanting to format a date.

I would act on the JavaScript `Date` object, something like:

```
var startDate = new Date(row[5]);
var weekDay;
switch (startDate.getDay()) {
  case 0: weekDay = "Sun"; break;
  case 1: weekDay = "Mon"; break;
  case 2: weekDay = "Tue"; break;
  case 3: weekDay = "Wed"; break;
  case 4: weekDay = "Thu"; break;
  case 5: weekDay = "Fri"; break;
  case 6: weekDay = "Sat"; break;
}
var month;
switch (startDate.getMonth()) {
  case 0: month = "Jan"; break;
  case 1: month = "Feb"; break;
  case 2: month = "Mar"; break;
  case 3: month = "Apr"; break;
  case 4: month = "May"; break;
  case 5: month = "Jun"; break;
  case 6: month = "Jul"; break;
  case 7: month = "Aug"; break;
  case 8: month = "Sep"; break;
  case 9: month = "Oct"; break;
  case 10: month = "Nov"; break;
  case 11: month = "Dec"; break;
}

var formattedDate = weekDay + " " + month + " " + startDate.getDate() + " " + startDate.getFullYear();
```

The variable `formattedDate` now holds a string like `Fri Feb 20 2015`.

If you want to do this by manipulating strings instead, and you're not concerned with the language settings of the spreadsheet, you could use

```
var startDate = row[5] + "";
var formattedDate = startDate.substring(0, 15);
```

Comment: I can try that, thanks but my question still remains... can I not accomplish this in terms of string handling?

Comment: You say you're trying to call `editAsText`, but as far as I can see, [that method is only available in Google Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) - not Spreadsheets.

Comment: Yea i realised recently... haha. So there is no way to use string handling from the info i get from a spread sheet?

Comment: You can make it a string, as with `row[5] + ""`. Then you're free to extract substrings from it. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Yes I have done this already and still doesn't seem to work... but I'm starting to thing there is a logic error somewhere else so I'm going to run through the code again to check...

Comment: Okay i found root of my problem there were some issues with the form that is linked to the spreadsheet, I got it working now thanks. The substring() method works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [.toDateString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp) method ?
See what this gives you:

```
var start = row[5];
var dateStr = start.toDateString();
Logger.log(dateStr)
```

Comment: Haven't tried this yet ... will do so now, then use the dateStr var to edit the string...

Comment: Just by using .toDateString() the output should be somehting like Fri Feb 20 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can format it the way you want by using this in the first place.

### Code

```
var start = row[5]; // "Fri Feb 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (SAST)"    
var newStart = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(start), "SAST", "EEE MMM d yyyy");
Logger.log(newStart);
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: tried this and it threw an object error of some sort...